# How can I make Emacs put files named like .#filename into another directory too

Tags: auto-save, lock-files

I want my autosave files and backup files, e.g. `#filename.org#` and `filename.org~` files, not to clutter the directory in my code repo that is in TypeScript.

I have popped into a way to place inside another directory and it worked. However, after that I have seen another file popping up with `.#filename.org`.

What is this file for? How can I make Emacs put them into another directory too?

Comment: It's a lockfile to prevent another emacs from overwriting your changes. There's no provision for putting them somewhere else (but you can turn them off by setting `create-lockfiles` to `nil`)

Comment: If teh file is saved the lock file is destroyed, that means in my specific case I actually do not need to have a way to make emacs create them in another dirctory. I did not want the emacs specific files to clutter my other editors direcotry view. Also one can add a gitignore file to ignore tracking those files, there are comprehensie ready made gitignore files for emacs and many things.

Answer (score 2):

emacs-28, which has just been released, comes with `lock-file-name-transforms`, which lets you place those lockfiles somewhere other than in the same directory.

Comment: If you are not accessing shared files, then turning off lock-files altogether is probably fine. If you /are/ accessing files shared with other emacs users, then the locks are only useful if everyone agrees on lock-file-name-transforms....

Comment: There's also the case where the other Emacs user is yourself with another instance of Emacs. I run into that surprisingly often.

Comment: Could you show how to use this?

Comment: `C-h v lock-file-name-transforms` explains how to use it.